# Oracleで複数テーブルに同じシーケンスをinsertする方法

Tags: oracle

Oracleにて、3つのテーブルに大量insertする処理で相談です。

データは3テーブルにそれぞれMAXで３０００件がinsertされる想定なので、最大でも合計９０００レコードが増えることになります。

A_table, B_table, C_tableそれぞれに `table_id` というカラムを持たせており、insertの時に同じ値を入れたいです。この `table_id` には `hoge_seq.nextval` で作成した数字を入れたいです。

実現方法としては、もしinsertするデータが３０００件の場合
毎回　`select hoge_seq.nextval from dual` を実行→連番を取得

```
insert into A_table (table_id) values(1)
insert into B_table (table_id) values(1)
insert into C_table (table_id) values(1)
```

これを３０００回繰り返さないといけないでしょうか？

それとも　`select hoge_seq.nextval from dual`　連番の取得をした後にinsertしたい件数分、数字をインクリメントさせて

```
insert into A_table (table_id) values(1)....(3000)
insert into B_table (table_id) values(1)....(3000)
insert into C_table (table_id) values(1)....(3000)
```

こっちの方がいいでしょうか？

DBへの負荷を考えたら後者の方がいい気がします
しかし、後者を採用した場合万が一途中で別の機能からテーブルにinsertが走った時に同じIdのデータが存在する可能性が出てきており悩んでいます

ご回答よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 3, accepted):

シーケンスはトランザクションとは無関係に更新されるので、整合性を保つには前者以外の方法は考えられません。
後者でやるのであれば、採番のためのテーブルを用意し、範囲が被らないよう排他制御する必要があるでしょう。

Comment: 後者の場合で整合性が保てなくなる場合があるかについてコメントで議論が行われ、一段落していたので、まとめる意図でチャットに移しました。長い議論の際はチャットの利用をお考えください： https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141621/discussion-on-answer-by-koz-oracleinsert

Answer (score 1):

既に解決しているようですが、気づいた点コメント残します。

私も迷わず前者を選択します。たしかにシーケンスを使う事で多少負荷は上がりますがそれは、ユニークな番号を取得する為のコストとして割り切るしかないと考えます。
マシンスペックにもよりますが9000レコードではこの違いを感じる事はないとおもいます。
ただ使い方によっては、想定以上に遅くなることがありますので以下のような事は念頭に設計してみてください

1. シーケンスのキャッシュ値をいくつにするのが適切か
2. なるべく同時に複数セッションから取得要求のかからない設計を心がける
   　　同時に複数セッションから取得要求をかけるとenq: SV – contentionという待機イベントが発生しはじめます。数万件程度ではそれほど気になりませんがそれ以上になると無視できないレベルです。
3. RAC環境においてはシングル環境よりシーケンスの発番コストが上がります。
4. シーケンスキャッシュ（デフォルト20）をもつOracleにおいて、複数セッションから同時にあるシーケンスを利用するのであれば時系列に番号が発番されないケースがありえます。
5. 同時複数セッションでの利用がなくとも、複数のシーケンスキャッシュ値を定義している場合飛び番の発生は避けられない事。（エラーが発生しなくともありえます）

補足
今回はDMLにてnextvalをする想定のようですが、Oracle12c以降のバージョンであれば自動採番機能があります。テーブルの対象カラムに自動採番機能を割り当てておけばアプリ側でnextvalする手間が省けるのでご検討ください。(但し今回のケースではこの方法は採用できません。Oracleの場合同じシーケンスを複数テーブルの自動採番機能に割り当てできないからです。）

Comment: 問われているのは「Oracleで複数テーブルに同じシーケンスをinsertする方法」です。
自動採番は、制約エラーなどで INSERT が失敗すると同期がとれなくなるので、これを紹介するのはちょっと違うのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 本質問の回答として全く問題ないと思いますよ。
程度が分からないので選択理由が明確でないとは思いましたが…。

Comment: A,B,Cの順に INSERTしていくとします。A の INSERT が失敗すると ROLLBACK すると思いますが、A の採番は進んでしまいます。B,C の採番は進みません。
失敗しても B,C を INSERT すれば同じように進みますが、そういう作りにはしないでしょう。

Comment: たしかにその通りですね。Oracleの自動採番は一つのシーケンスを複数テーブルで共有できないですから。
ここで案内したの不適切だったかもしれませんが、まぁ、ここまでのやり取り残っていれば読まれるかたも戸惑うこともないでしょうからそのままコメントはのこしておきますね。

Comment: いやいや、hoge_seq1つでないとダメに決まってるでしょ。。。
トランザクションの意味がありません
なんで勝手にsequence増やしてるんですか・・・

Comment: >dameo さん
ORACLE の自動採番は、１つのテーブルに対し、自動的にシーケンスを作って割り当てます。
なのでテーブルが３つあれば３つのシーケンスが出来ちゃうんですよ。

Comment: 別にマスターを1つにすればいいだけだと思いますが、簡単に共有できないので効率は悪いですよね。

Answer (score 0):

### 回答ではありません。

例えばこんな方法で入れるのもありという内容です。

#### SQL

```sql
-- DDL
CREATE SEQUENCE hoge_seq;
CREATE TABLE A_table(id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR2(10));
CREATE TABLE B_table(id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR2(10));
CREATE TABLE C_table(id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR2(10));
CREATE TABLE tmp_to_insert(aval VARCHAR2(10), bval VARCHAR2(10), cval varchar2(10));

-- データロードは適当なツール(sql loaderの最速オプション指定など)でtmp_to_insertに突っ込む。ココでは普通に入れる。
insert into tmp_to_insert values('foo1', 'bar1', 'hoge1');
insert into tmp_to_insert values('foo2', 'bar2', 'hoge2');
insert into tmp_to_insert values('foo3', 'bar3', 'hoge3');
commit;
-- ちゃんと入ったか確認
select * from tmp_to_insert;

-- 後は流し込むだけ
INSERT ALL
INTO A_table(id, value) values(hoge_seq.nextval, aval)
INTO B_table(id, value) values(hoge_seq.nextval, bval)
INTO C_table(id, value) values(hoge_seq.nextval, cval)
SELECT * FROM tmp_to_insert;

-- 確認
SELECT *
FROM A_table A
    inner join B_table B on B.id=A.id
    inner join C_table C on C.id=B.id
;
commit;

-- 後始末
drop table tmp_to_insert cascade constraints purge;
```

#### 実行結果

```
[root@cc15414f91d5 ~]# sqlplus system/oracle@database:1521 <hoge.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Dec 14 17:39:14 2022
Version 21.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Dec 14 2022 17:37:38 +00:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> SQL> 
Sequence created.

SQL> 
Table created.

SQL> 
Table created.

SQL> 
Table created.

SQL> 
Table created.

SQL> SQL> SQL> 
1 row created.

SQL> 
1 row created.

SQL> 
1 row created.

SQL> 
Commit complete.

SQL> SQL> 
AVAL       BVAL       CVAL
---------- ---------- ----------
foo1       bar1       hoge1
foo2       bar2       hoge2
foo3       bar3       hoge3

SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5  
9 rows created.

SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5  
        ID VALUE              ID VALUE              ID VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 foo1                1 bar1                1 hoge1
         2 foo2                2 bar2                2 hoge2
         3 foo3                3 bar3                3 hoge3

SQL> 
Commit complete.

SQL> SQL> SQL> 
Table dropped.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0
[root@cc15414f91d5 ~]#
```

※Oracle Database 21c Express Edition